# how to transfer hard drive from on pc to another, HDD contains grub (dual boot win10 and ubuntu gnome)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd

I need to transfer my SSD that has dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu Gnome 3 to my secondary PC. I tried to simply take the disk out and put it in that secondary pc but than I'm having problem loading **grub**. In my primary PC bios is showing two bootloaders one from windows and one from ubuntu (grub I think) and my secondary PC is (in bios) showing only SSD as one.

Along side SSD i have regular HDD that serves me as backup so I think I won't have problems with transfering him along side SSD.

thanks in advance, Leo :)

Comment: I'm hoping there is a way to avoid reinstalling everything, Those instalations are up on that disk for 2 and half years

Comment: Is system UEFI or BIOS? And Windows is licensed to one system only, although the free upgrade to Windows 10 will soon expire. New UEFI systems have Windows Product key embedded in UEFI.

Comment: It is UEFI, yeah I know about that new windows licencing thing. I have new licence ready if I need to change that.

Comment: Is new system also UEFI. UEFI forgets its NVRAM boot settings when a drive is disconnected. You just may need to add new settings with efibootmgr? Some UEFI find .efi files and add them automatically. After rebooting (cold boot, so UEFI scans system) a couple of times, and going into UEFI, do you see any entries from ESP - efi system partition.

Answer (score 0):

Before proceeding please backup any documents on your computer to an external drive. You could do this by either putting the SSD back into the old computer or using a Live CD.

Whilst not the same issue, the instructions on the below page should fix the problem you're getting.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Any problems, let me know! :)